# Why do I keep getting free GTA V money from Rockstar? Is it safe to use?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Every time I play GTA V on my Xbox One, Rockstar gives me $500,000. I don't play too often, and I only play about once every two weeks. This kept happening and I ended up getting a total of $4 million. I did not take advantage of this because I thought that was cheating. Anyways, I recently got onto GTA V Online and Rockstar messaged me saying not to cheat or hack and if I do, my account will get banned. I have had this account for about a year and a half now and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes Rockstar offer [rebates on shark card purchases](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/218230928) or for items a player has purchased that [once cost money but are now free](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/208990887). I believe they've done it before to apologise for server downtime, and then sometimes they just [give money away for free](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201026343).

Feel free to spend they money you've received. I received $500,000 recently myself just because they felt like it.

Comment: But do you think I would get banned>

Comment: No, not for spending the money they've given. Rockstar are able to trace money back to its source so they will know if you've gained it legitmately or not.